# python regex find first word after certain keywords

Tags: python, regex

I have the following python code that retrieves first word after certain keywords:

```
file_tokens = ('DATABASE', 'EXTERNAL_FILE', 'FILE', 'FILENAME', 'INCLUDE')
# match newline, only spaces, then exact token, then spaces, then everything but whitespace
search_pattern = r'\n\s*({})\s+([^\s]*)'.format('|'.join(file_tokens))
matches = re.findall(search_pattern, file_content_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)  # find matches
```

It is working beautifully in a string like the following (including new lines and carriage returns):

```
# originaly spe1 but with grd ecl file meddled with for nesting 
include tests

SIMULATION
  SIMULATION_TYPE SUBSURFACE
  PROCESS_MODELS
    SUBSURFACE_FLOW Flow
      MODE BLACK_OIL
      OPTIONS
       ANALYTICAL_JACOBIAN
       ISOTHERMAL
      /
    / ! end of subsurface_flow
  / ! end of process models
  CHECKPOINT
  /
END  !! end simulation block

SUBSURFACE

external_file example1.dat

include example2.dat
```

with matches containing:

> matches = [example1.dat, example2.dat]

but it is failing for a simple string like the following containing only keywords and other text:

```
external_file example3.dat

include example4.dat
```

returning an empty array or just the last item (a bit random):

> matches = [example4.dat] or matches =[]

any idea? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

OK, after modifying the import text:

```
external_file example3.dat

include example4.dat

database example5.dat
```

I have realised that my matches array is missing only the first item:

> matches = [example4.dat, example5.dat]

How do I modify the regex to include example3.dat?

Comment: removing `\n` will include `tests` in matches so if you only want files you may need to change the regex to something like: `({})\s+([^\s]*\.[^\s]*)`

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it slightly different.

```py
import re
test1 = """include tests

SIMULATION
  SIMULATION_TYPE SUBSURFACE
  PROCESS_MODELS
    SUBSURFACE_FLOW Flow
      MODE BLACK_OIL
      OPTIONS
       ANALYTICAL_JACOBIAN
       ISOTHERMAL
      /
    / ! end of subsurface_flow
  / ! end of process models
  CHECKPOINT
  /A
END  !! end simulation block

SUBSURFACE

external_file example1.dat

include example2.dat"""

test2 = """external_file example3.dat

include example4.dat"""

token = re.findall(r'\S+', test1)
token
>>>['include',
 'tests',
 'SIMULATION',
 'SIMULATION_TYPE',
 'SUBSURFACE',
 'PROCESS_MODELS',
 'SUBSURFACE_FLOW',
 'Flow',
 'MODE',
 'BLACK_OIL',
 'OPTIONS',
 'ANALYTICAL_JACOBIAN',
 'ISOTHERMAL',
 '/',
 '/',
 '!',
 'end',
 'of',
 'subsurface_flow',
 '/',
 '!',
 'end',
 'of',
 'process',
 'models',
 'CHECKPOINT',
 '/',
 'END',
 '!!',
 'end',
 'simulation',
 'block',
 'SUBSURFACE',
 'external_file',
 'example1.dat',
 'include',
 'example2.dat']
```

When you have tokenized your words, I would build bi-grams

```py
bi_grams = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(token[:-1], token[1:]) ]
```

and then filter those bi-grams that contain your file tokens as a first entry

```py
file_tokens = ('DATABASE', 'EXTERNAL_FILE', 'FILE', 'FILENAME', 'INCLUDE')
bi_grams_of_interest = [bi_gram for bi_gram in bi_grams if bi_gram[0].upper() in file_tokens]
bi_grams_of_interest
>>>[('include', 'tests'),
 ('external_file', 'example1.dat'),
 ('include', 'example2.dat')]
```

if you run this for test2 I get the following output

```py
>>>[('external_file', 'example3.dat'), ('include', 'example4.dat')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\n` with `^` and add `re.M` to the flags:

```
r'(?mi)^\s*(?:{})\s+(\S+)'.format('|'.join(file_tokens))
```

Now, `^\s*` will match the start of a line and then 0 or more whitespaces.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jJIAWn):

```
import re

file_content_string="""external_file example3.dat

include example4.dat

database example5.dat"""

file_tokens = ('DATABASE', 'EXTERNAL_FILE', 'FILE', 'FILENAME', 'INCLUDE')
search_pattern = r'^\s*(?:{})\s+(\S+)'.format('|'.join(file_tokens))
matches = re.findall(search_pattern, file_content_string, flags=re.I|re.M) 
print(matches)
```

Output: `['example3.dat', 'example4.dat', 'example5.dat']`